# Python help! I'm stuck on a syntax error that I don't know how to fix. Using version 3.4.1

Tags: python

The program list the prime numbers from 1 to 100, but when running it I get and syntax error on the "print p". 
Whats wrong??

```
for p in range(2, n+1):
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p % i == 0:
            break
        else:
            print p
print ("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python 3? If so, `print` is a function, and always requires parenthesis when you call it. For example:

```
print(p)
```

Comment: More info: https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function